# Sub-filter in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx to forward my request to the Application , were i have added a sub-filter to forward the application URL instead of the internal FQDN..

Sample: sub_filter 'http://XXX.x.sample.com:8000' 'https://example.sample.com';

when the sub_filter is triggered ideal case should be that "https://example.sample.com" should be visible is address bar, but i can see "http://XXX.x.sample.com:8000"